# Smoothly animated hole in CALayer?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, calayer, caanimation

Ok, I figured out how to do this based on various posts here on SO, and it works great. I'm working on an overlay which will basically mask the whole window except for a small region. This is for drawing attention to a specific area of my app. I'm using a bunch of calls to `moveToPoint:` and `addLineToPoint:` like so (this is in my CALayer subclass' `drawInContext:`):

```
....

// inner path (CW)
[holePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];
[holePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w, y)];
[holePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + w, y + h)];
[holePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y+h)];

// outer path (CCW)
[holePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(xBounds, yBounds)];
[holePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xBounds, yBounds + hBounds)];
[holePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xBounds + wBounds, yBounds + hBounds)];
[holePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xBounds + wBounds, yBounds)];

// put the path in the context
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, 0);
CGContextAddPath(ctx, holePath.CGPath);
CGContextClosePath(ctx);

// set the color
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, self.overlayColor.CGColor);

// draw the overlay
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

(`holePath` is an instance of `UIBezierPath`.)

So far so good. The next step is animation. In order to do this (I also found this technique here on SO) I made a method as follows

```
-(CABasicAnimation *)makeAnimationForKey:(NSString *)key {
    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:key];
    anim.fromValue = [[self presentationLayer] valueForKey:key];
    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    anim.duration = 0.5;

    return anim;
}
```

and overrode `actionForKey:`, `initWithLayer:` and `needsDisplayForKey:` (returning the result of `makeAnimationForKey:` in `actionForKey:`. Now, I get a nice "hole layer", which has a property `holeRect` which is animatable using implicit CAAnimations! Unfortunately, it's SUPER choppy. I get something like 2 or 3 frames per second. I thought that perhaps the problem was the background, and tried replacing it with a snapshot, but no dice. Then, I used Instruments to profile, and discovered that the HUGE hog here is the call to `CGContextDrawPath()`.

tl;dr I guess my question comes down to this: is there a simpler way to create this layer with a hole in it which will redraw faster? My hunch is that, if I could simplify the path I'm using, drawing the path would be lighter. Or possibly masking? Please help!

Comment: seriously? nobody has ANYTHING to say about this? is my question too long?

Comment: Try using CAShapeLayer and animate the path.

Comment: Can a CAShapeLayer have a hole in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I tried phix23's suggestion, and it totally did the trick! At first, I was subclassing `CALayer` and adding a `CAShapeLayer` as a sublayer, but I couldn't get it to work properly and I'm pretty tired at this point, so I gave up and just replaced my subclass completely with `CAShapeLayer`! I used the above code in its own method, returning the `UIBezierPath`, and animated like so:

```
UIBezierPath* oldPath = [self pathForHoleRect:self.holeRect];
UIBezierPath* newPath = [self pathForHoleRect:rectToHighlight];
self.holeRect = rectToHighlight;

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
animation.duration = 0.5;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
animation.fromValue = (id)oldPath.CGPath;
animation.toValue = (id)newPath.CGPath;
[self.holeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animatePath"];
self.holeLayer.path = newPath.CGPath;
```

Interesting side note -- `path` is NOT implicitly animatable. I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Redrawing is expensive, animation is not. When you set the value for "holeRect" you are instructing the entire layer to redraw. **THIS IS NOT THE SAME AS A TYPICAL PERFORMANCE OPTIMIZED PROPERTY ANIMATION.** If the layer is the size of the entire screen, then you are effectively recreating a new version of the layer on every frame. This is one of the things that apple does to ensure smooth animations. You want to prevent redraws as much as possible.

I would suggest creating a layer with the hole in the center, and make sure that the layer is large enough to cover the entire screen no matter where the hole is centered. Then the animation should animate the "position" property of the layer. While it may seem wasteful to have this massive layer of which only ~ 30% will ever be used at once, it is much less wasteful then redrawing on every frame. If you would like to maintain your "holeRect" interface you can, but the layer with "holeRect" property should contain a sublayer or sublayers that are animated in the way that I described (in layoutSubviews, not drawInContext:).

In summary, make sure you are animating position, opacity, transform as these are among the most efficient animations on layers, and redraw only when necessary.

Comment: See my comment on @wanderwaltz's answer (and my answer I'm working on posting right now). Will position, opacity, transform be a lot faster than `CAShapeLayer`'s path property?

Answer (score 0):

In your example you use a rectangular hole. Implementing such animation could be more efficient if you use four rectangular layers (see attached image). To animate the hole rectangle position you'll have to animate the blue layers' widths, and red layers' heights. (if the hole rectangle can change width, the red layers' widths will also have to be animated)

If you need a non-rectangular hole, you could place another layer in the middle of these, which has the hole inside and change only the position of this layer (see the 2nd image). Resizing this non-rectangular hole will result in recreating only the middle layer's contents, so it should be a bit faster than in your original case where this layer was of the size of the screen if I understood correctly.

[image: Multilayer approach]
[image: Multilayer approach, non-rectangular hole]

Comment: Sounds plausible. I've solved the problem though (about to post my solution) using `CAShapeLayer` as suggested by @phix23. Not sure that this would be measurably faster than that, but perhaps I'll try it. Seems like four layers instead of one will be worse, and also it might be hard to get the overlap to seem seamless?

Answer (score -1):

I am posting an anwser because I am not able to comment on your question (yet) due to reputation.

My question is whether this has to be created programmatically? If it is just about creating an attention area you could use another approach.

Why not just use a black png with a transparent hole in it? Then you do not have performance issues during animation and to a certain extent if you choose your original hole size well, you could even resize it. The image has to be just big enough so that it covers every part of the view indenpendently of the current position of the hole. The part outside the hole could also include transparency resulting in a shadow effect outside the attention area.

Comment: I suppose I could do it that way. The disadvantage will be that I'll have to mess up the aspect ratio for some highlight regions. It will be hard to have a nice shadow (which is super easy with CALayer). It's certainly not the elegant solution I'm looking for, but would probably be faster...

Comment: Ah, yes I understand. Thanks for the comment. There sould be a better way.